# How to have full directory path always shown in mac terminal?

Tags: terminal

I found [answers](https://superuser.com/a/239995/195425) but they don't work:
I added this line in `.bash_profile`:

```
export PS1='\u@\H:\w$'
```

It outputs:

```
\u@\H:\w$
```

Instead of:

```
user@host:my/Current/Path/In/This/Terminal/Window$
```

Comment: what is the full path to .bash_profile file?

Comment: /Users/<User>/.bash_profile

Comment: For the OP.  Seeing if you didn't put the command somewhere else and not his ~/ folder.

Comment: can you post your .bash_profile?  I reproduced this only if I leave out the single ticks in the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I just removed `oh my zsh` I had to change terminal settings a little:

`Terminal -> Preferences -> Startup tab`, and change "Shell Opens With:" from "Default login shell" to Command and value `/bin/bash`.

Now string `export PS1='\u@\H:\w$'` works correct.

Comment: I put a space after `w$` but before `'` so the command prompt looks better when you type commands.

Answer (score 2):

With macOS Catalina, the default shell is zsh. You can either switch to the /bin/bash shell as explained in Maxim's answer. Or stay with the zsh shell and change the startup run command to say

```
PROMPT='%/ %# '
```

The %/ is for full path and %# is to indicate whether the shell is running with privileges. More explanation and the full list of customizations is [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion).

I found this info [here](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-06-customizing-the-zsh-prompt/).

You can add the startup run command mentioned above in the 'Run command: ' field at Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Shell > Startup.  This is what I did. You could instead add the command to the .zshrc file as well. Either way, quit and restart the terminal for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Given how old the original question is, the chances that the user was using Bash are quite high.

Comment: Yes. I just added this here in case someone on Catalina comes here with the same question. Sorry if I posted in the wrong place.